# Holomorphic function in a strip

Tags: complex-analysis

I was confused about some statements in Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, one of which is as follows.

> (Page 121) Suppose $\hat{f}$ satisfies the decay condition $|\hat{f}(\xi)| \leq Ae^{-2\pi a|\xi|}$ for some constants $a, A>0$. Then $f(x)$ is the restriction to $\mathbb{R}$ of a function $f(z)$ holomorphic in the strip $S_b = \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |\mathrm{Im}(z)|<b\}$, for any $0 < b < a$.

My question is about the reason they stated $S_b$ for any $0<b<a$. **Is it not equivalent to say $f(z)$ holomorphic in the strip $S_a$?**

My reasoning: It is trivial that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $S_a$, then it is holomorphic in $S_b$ when $0 < b < a$. Conversely, for any $z_0 \in S_a$, there exists some $b$ such that $|\mathrm{Im}(z)| < b < a$ since $S_a$ is open. Hence $f(z)$ being holomorphic in $S_b$ implies it being holomorphic at $z_0$. Finally $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $S_a$ because of $z_0$ can be chosen arbitrarily.

---

Am I missing something in the reasoning? If not, could there be any particular reason not to simply say $S_a$?

Comment: You are not missing anything.

Comment: You're right. Maybe the proof has the property that proving it for $S_b$ works better than  proving it directly for $S_a$???

Comment: Or maybe they go on to say something you don't mention here that's true in $S_b$ but not in $S_a$, like some growth condition or something?